# ASP.NET 4.5 System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, overflow, asp.net-4.5

- IIS version 6.2 (build 9200)
- Application pool .NET 4.5 Integrated
- AWS Windows Server 2012 R2
- MySQL community db

I moved my ASP.NET 4.5 application over from Windows Server 2008 to an AWS instance, Windows Server 2012 R2 Base. I was able to get everything setup but application now errors out at below code. If I comment out below code, then same error occurs at another read from database or Int32 conversion:

```
lblQuote.Text = "'" + drQuotes["quote"].ToString() + "'&nbsp;(";
```

> Stack Trace:     OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in
>   an overflow.    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)
>   +359    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i) +57    path.DisplayQuote() in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dreamplaybook\path.aspx.cs:764
>   path.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dreamplaybook\path.aspx.cs:180
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178   Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

After setting up my new MySQL instance in AWS Windows 2012, I recreated the database by running my sqldump code from previous MySQL Windows 2008 instance. Below is sample code to create table where drQuotes would be reading accessing.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `dpsurvey_quote`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dpsurvey_quote`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `dpsurvey_quote` (
  `quoteID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `qCategoryID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `careerID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `quote` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`quoteID`),
  KEY `qCategoryID` (`qCategoryID`),
  KEY `fk_dpsurvey_quote_careerID` (`careerID`),
  CONSTRAINT `dpsurvey_quote_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`qCategoryID`) REFERENCES `dpsurvey_qcategory` (`qCategoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dpsurvey_quote_careerID` FOREIGN KEY (`careerID`) REFERENCES `dpsurvey_career` (`careerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Things that I've tried so far that haven't worked:

1. Can't find these settings in Visual Studio advanced build configuration because it is a web app. a) Unchecked keyword so would ignore overflow and b) I also couldn't find Prefer 32-bit setting
2. I tried using unchecked {} blocks around errored code but didn't work
3. Where error was occurring at Int32, I changed to Int64 but still errored out

Thanks very much for your help! I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Comment: Have you tried collation solution from this link  http://forums.asp.net/t/1665606.aspx?MySQL+OdbcDataAdapter+error+System+Data+Odbc+OdbcDataReader+GetSqlType+Int32+i+ ?

Comment: Thank you. Not working but think we are close.

Collation was set to "latin1_swedish_ci" and causing field to be mediumtext instead of text. So I recreated database using CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; I reran source sqldump.sql file but still no.

mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_general_ci      |
+--------------------------+----------------------+

Comment: Dmitry - question resolved. In addition to your link, I also needed to update my connection strings in web.config file to MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver. Before doing this, I needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package and then install MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver. If you try to install the driver first, you will receive Error 1918. Error installing ODBC driver MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver. Thank you!